# Why the mouse's p->dx and p->dy are always zero?

Tags: linux, kernel

I add some traces into Linux kernel source code of mousedev_packet() (in mousedev.c). I want to see the coordinates change when I moving mouse from kernel printk. But it seems a little strange.

```
static void mousedev_packet(struct mousedev_client *client,
                signed char *ps2_data)
{
    struct mousedev_motion *p = &client->packets[client->tail];
    int val;
    printk(KERN_WARNING "..................tomxue: case 19.................");

    ps2_data[0] = 0x08 |
        ((p->dx < 0) << 4) | ((p->dy < 0) << 5) | (p->buttons & 0x07);
    ps2_data[1] = mousedev_limit_delta(p->dx, 127);
    ps2_data[2] = mousedev_limit_delta(p->dy, 127);
    p->dx -= ps2_data[1];
    p->dy -= ps2_data[2];
    val = p->dx;
    printk(KERN_WARNING "mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=%d ps2_data[2] =%d.................", ps2_data[1], ps2_data[2]);
    printk(KERN_WARNING "mousedev_packet: p->dx=%d p->dy=%d p=%p val=%d.................", p->dx, p->dy, p, val);
```

The dmesg is below:

```
[  105.631164] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.631195] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.639160] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-25 ps2_data[2] =3.................
[  105.639160] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.639190] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.647155] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-26 ps2_data[2] =3.................
[  105.647155] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.647186] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.655151] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-24 ps2_data[2] =5.................
[  105.655181] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.655212] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.663543] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-19 ps2_data[2] =6.................
[  105.663543] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.663574] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.671142] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-17 ps2_data[2] =6.................
[  105.671173] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.671173] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.679168] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-13 ps2_data[2] =5.................
[  105.679168] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.679199] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.687133] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-8 ps2_data[2] =3.................
[  105.687164] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.687194] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.695190] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-4 ps2_data[2] =1.................
[  105.695190] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.695220] mousedev_read data=�s�$......................
[  105.703155] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-5 ps2_data[2] =0.................
[  105.703186] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  105.703186] mousedev_read data=�......................
[  106.047302] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=0 ps2_data[2] =1.................
[  106.047302] mouMinicom2.5Minicom2.5Minicom2.5sedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
[  106.047332] mousedev_read data......................
```

And as you can see, `p->dx` and `p->dy` are always zero, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes sense to me.

Looking at this output:

```
[  105.639160] mousedev_packet: ps2_data[1]=-25 ps2_data[2] =3.................
[  105.639160] mousedev_packet: p->dx=0 p->dy=0 p=dd9b6a10 val=0.................
```

It seems that at this line

```
ps2_data[1] = mousedev_limit_delta(p->dx, 127);
```

`p->dx` is `-25`, and you're setting `ps2_data[1]` to be `-25` as well.

Then at this line:

```
p->dx -= ps2_data[1];
```

You're setting `p->dx` to `p->dx - ps2_data[1]`. Or, `-25 - -25` is `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I should check it more carefully.